# Camel bean binding tries to convert the body to Exchange

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I have a simple route which looks like this:

```
<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="routeA">
    <from uri="cxfrs://bean://simpleCxf" />
    <log message="The message body contains ${body}"/>
    <to uri="direct-vm:RouteB" />
</route>

<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="routeB">
    <from uri="direct-vm:RouteB" />
    <bean ref="requestValidator" method="validateRequest" />
    <log message="The input message ${body}" />
    <bean ref="dbClient" method="queryDatabase" />
</route>
```

the cxf configuration is also pretty simple:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="simpleCxf" address="/test"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    serviceClass="com.gogol.test.TestResource">
</cxf:rsServer>
```

This simple route fails with the below exception

```
No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value [com.gogol.test.resource.SimpleObject@773736ca]
```

This is the message history which suggests that it is failing at the point `<bean ref="requestValidator" method="validateRequest" />`

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId ProcessorId                   Processor                      Elapsed (ms)
[routeA] [routeA] [direct-vm://routeA                                ] [6]
[routeB] [log12 ] [log                                               ] [2]
[routeB] [to9   ] [direct-vm:routeA                                  ] [4]
[routeA] [bean26] [bean[ref:requestValidator method: validateRequest]] [2]
```

I think the issue is that Camel is trying to convert the body generated by cxf to an Exchange object. Because the requestValidator class has a method which has a signature of:

```
public void validateRequest(Exchange exchange) thows SomeException.
```

But ideally the message generated by cxf should be set as a body inside Exchange. Am I correct, if not then what could be the reason of the above exception?

EDIT:

I am using CXF version 3.0.4.redhat-621084
and CAMEL version 2.15.1.redhat-621084

```
{Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.apache.camel.Exchange but has value: [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67] of type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList on: Message: [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67]. Exchange[Message: [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67]]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67]]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:101)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$42.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:1037)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value [com.gogol.schema.TestResourcec@6b651b67]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:177)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiTypeConverter.mandatoryConvertTo(OsgiTypeConverter.java:122)[203:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        ... 69 more}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive on the camel xml dsl how to format this properly, but you can always explicitly tell camel to do a type conversion.  You could test your theory by using a convertBodyTo call to force a type conversion.

```
from("myEndpoint")
    .log("This is my previous object")
    .convertBodyTo(TestResource.class)
    .log("This is my object after a camel type conversion");
```

Comment: I have tried to convert the way you have mentioned but the only difference it makes is replace the MessageContentsList with TestResource in the exception. 

Without the convertBodyTo method the excpetion says:
No type converter available to convert from type **MessageContentsList** to the required type : Exchange

With the convertBodyTo method the exception says:
No type converter available to convert from type **TestResource** to the required type : Exchange.

Comment: Ok if you tried that then it looks like you might be having trouble with camel thinking it needs a type converter to convert the MessageContentsList to an exchange, but since that should be just the body of your exchange it shouldn't be type converting.  Can you set your camel context to TRACE and add show the output?

Comment: Which objects control Camel's thinking? As per camel's bean binding strategy the Exchange should not be taken as any other Class for data conversion. Also if I change the validateRequest method's argument to TestResource then camel calls the method just fine. But then I dont get a way to set the exchange body. Any thoughts please?

Comment: If your just trying to replace the body of the exchange then simply return an Object and camel will automatically set that the the IN message body of the existing exchange for you.  As for why its trying to force a type conversion to exchange I am still not sure.  It might be a bug, but this would have to be replicated in the simplest form and then a Jira opened